# How to get rid of small indent after a defined "aligned equation" environment

Tags: spacing, equations, environments

I have defined an environment called `\equ`, which is an aligned equation environment to save time when writing a thesis with lots of equations.

However, after using this environment there is a small indent, which is not there if I just use the `\begin{equation}` and `\begin{aligned}` commands directly (see MWE):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newenvironment{equ}[1]
{\begin{equation} \label{equation:#1}
    \begin{aligned}
}
{
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}
}



\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
This is the first paragraph of text in the document. It is not indented, as expected.

This is the second paragraph of text in the document. It is indented, as expected.

\begin{equation}\label{equation:1}
\begin{aligned}
    F &= m a\\
    E &= m c^{2}
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
This is the paragraph after an equation. It is not indented, as expected.
\begin{equ}{1}
F &= ma\\
E &= m c^{2}
\end{equ}
This is the paragraph after an equ.
It is indented with a small indent, and the vertical spacing around the equation looks slightly different, but I don't know why?!

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am fairly new to this; I'm sure it's something obvious so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: And: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our site.